# QML circular image "waves effect" artefacts

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm building a qml application and I would like to implement a circle with a "wave" effect inside.
I've more or less succeeded except that the result is this graphic artefact... can anyone help me?

The problem:

[image: PROBLEM]

Source image:

[image: SORUCE]

Working example **without** circle:
[image: WORKING WITHOUT CIRCLE]

I state that I've NEVER used qml in my life and this is the third day I've been working on it, of course I'm trying to read documentation etc. but i have no idea what happened, this is the code:

```
//QT PK
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
//JS PK
import "componentCreation.js" as MyScript

ApplicationWindow 
{
    id: window
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("window")
    width: 1600
    height: 900
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    color: "transparent"

    property real slideValue
    signal onSlide(real value)

    Image 
    {
        id: img
        source: '/home/patan/code/QML/pic/contents/images/Waves.png'
        property bool rounded: true
        property bool adapt: true

        //MAKE IMAGE CIRCULAR
        layer.enabled: rounded
        layer.effect: OpacityMask 
        {
            maskSource: Item 
            {
                width: img.width
                height: img.height
            
                Rectangle 
                {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    width: img.adapt ? img.width : Math.min(img.width, img.height)
                    height: img.adapt ? img.height : width
                    radius: Math.min(width, height)
                }
            }
        }
        //WAVE EFFECT
        ShaderEffect 
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            property variant source: img
            property real frequency: 1
            property real amplitude: 0.1
            property real time: 0.0
            NumberAnimation on time 
            {
                from: 0; to: Math.PI*2; duration: 10000; loops: Animation.Infinite
            }
            fragmentShader: "
                            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                            uniform sampler2D source;
                            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                            uniform highp float frequency;
                            uniform highp float amplitude;
                            uniform highp float time;
                            void main() {
                                highp vec2 texCoord = qt_TexCoord0;
                                texCoord.y = amplitude * sin(time * frequency + texCoord.x * 6.283185) + texCoord.y;
                                gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, texCoord) * qt_Opacity;
                            }"
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive me if this is terrible code quality, if anyone can help me get it working I would appreciate it

Comment: Does it work any better if the ShaderEffect is not a child of `img`?

Comment: You could try to use a `Rectangle` with `radius: width / 2` and `clip: true` instead of the `OpacityMask`. Might be that those two effects fight each other. I can't verify that, because I don't have Qt 5 available anymore.
Note: Don't use QtQuick.Controls 1

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to your solution.

I created an `SVG` icon that has the wave effect applied. Then I stretch the `SVG` icon to fill the screen. Then I use `Image.Tile` to fill the wave repeatedly and then I use the `NumberAnimation` to shift the `SVG` icon `x`.

Then, I apply an `OpacityMask` to cut out a circle:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Page {
    id: window
    
    property real slide: 0.0
    
    Item {
        id: waveEffect
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            height: window.height
            width: window.width + 4 * window.height
            x: -window.height * 2 + slide
            source: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="32" height="32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#0F325B"/>
<path d="M ${wave()} 32 16 32 32 0 32" fill="#5294E2"/>
</svg>`
            sourceSize: Qt.size(height, height)
            fillMode: Image.Tile
        }
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id: circleEffect
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            width: Math.min(window.height, window.width)
            height: width
            radius: width / 2
            color: "red"
        }
        visible: false
    }
    
    NumberAnimation {
        target: window
        property: "slide"
        from: window.height
        to: 0
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        duration: 8000
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: waveEffect
        source: waveEffect
        maskSource: circleEffect
    }

    function wave() {
        let str = [ ];
        for (let j = 0; j<32; j++) {
            let a = j * 2 * Math.PI / 32;
            let i = Math.sin(a) * 2 + 16;
            str.push(`${j} ${i.toFixed(2)} `);
        }
        return str.join(" ");
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAF0niclVRtT9swEP7eX3HK+NBSFrIUEEsp0oZg6oduMPZtmlSTOO0Vx45sh5eh/vddnLRpoJ02q7J8uefenytmudIWbuxNgfF9B1uif6Gk1UqY5vvxhcpyZv0vmuVzjJm4TFMeW9O5ZjMOLx2gg0kEjygT9ehEd+Va5VzbZ9CcCTACEx5B4AcNYmx5VjtYO2EPvPK//sxkPFfa+CkKEUHONJeNcpw1SazOnONsblcJ+ZXYQjxiYudrgJOgD0ew/xebpwjet7SEDsnKFdZCGlXomGqdJsyyCMsMD83DrP+UiWFh09ODM5KqHEbeIPTqhN37vHOmqfgdWih7MPLeBVeD8Pizd0homswckpE3gb2Xsnnd3hIGIXw4KW/6BbBhdxx+PLoMnV2Z0fl0S963+Jtyv7G+oUe3Cn5QJ9Fr4UunE1VO1U3B/4GiacRy/XpAg3eCUCkTpgIsO7vmH6OOxX8x4DshmZyJ1yyoZzyh/vgZym5rdget2fd20IdULY1mCRam1sAhhC1trITSEXiaJ96/tqG83fW1yO64/iSJLRaV3KjFMj3jtrVe5VltFwV0DGxCplplu8hvFa3gWhJK5VTOOqo/lilKtM0UdSElylkEVhfN16TQDh/BaRAEmxP9lrMY7fOEmfuNEtrz27Liq43ZosrI1W2tfkOOOmpayNh1rVqAjciCWzBWwwh+wq9h0yKloVvqFqQJhrA4G4R09/u9VyQqMYwwC7fs+xWbrsc0ezJ4g0RCOoQhvrFe/Qfx4aSNpHz8vDDz7nTvZbGktUXfqit84kk3pOWd9oZb2KO5LbR0tgtF3j3watyys/wDCCqVPA==)